# How to get the available space in internal memory on an emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using an emulator to test my app and I need to get the available space on the internal memory.

```
StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
long availavleSpace  = ((long) statFs.getAvailableBlocks() *  (long) statFs.getBlockSize());
```

That piece of code is working on a normal device but on the emulator statFs.getAvailableBlocks() is returning 0. I have set the internal memory on my emulator to be 400MB. Is there something else that I have to do on the emulator to get the available internal memory space?